# Entity Framework IsRequired with AllowEmptyStrings=false

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I have a entity property defined as follows

```
 public virtual string Subject { get; set; }
```

and its mapped as

```
 this.Property(t => t.Subject)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255);
```

but this does not provide validation for empty strings. Can i specify following constraint using fluent api ?

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
        public virtual string Subject { get; set; }
```

Comment: I would also like to know if there is a way to set a "global" option for AllowEmptyStrings for the entire model inside OnModelCreating rather than having to set on every string value. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot because fluent-api describes mapping to database whereas the attribute with not allowed empty strings describes validation. Only subset of validation rules can be translated to mapping.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try overriding the `OnModelCreating` method in your DbContext class ?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().Property(x => x.Subject).IsRequired();
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: yes, thats where the mapping is, it checks for null strings, but not for empty